Not able to install ruby 3.2.2 in Mac Sequoia 15.0.1. M2 chip
I am trying to install ruby-3.2.2 on mac using RVM as a package manager, but I am getting errors related to openssl@1.1. Not only for ruby-3.2.2, for older versions also I am getting same error.
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install openssl@1.1',
please read /Users/pramod/.rvm/log/1730774114_ruby-3.2.2/package_install_openssl@1.1.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.

Earlier I am able to install ruby-3.2.2. I have checked above log file, I found this.
+requirements_osx_brew_libs_install:2> brew install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config coreutils libyaml openssl@1.1 --force
Error: openssl@1.1 has been disabled because it is not supported upstream! It was disabled on 2024-10-24.

Where it is trying to install openssl@1.1 where as it is already deprecated. I have installed openssl@3. I have tried pointing rvm to use openssl@3 like below
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)"
rvm install ruby-3.2.2 -C --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/etc/openssl@3

and tried all approaches, still getting error at openssl@1.1. How can I resolve this? I am using rvm as a package manager to install ruby versions. Need help!

Have you tried to update RVM? There have been several fixed related to openssl on macos this year. You likely want to use the head version here given that stable was last updated four years ago...

Thank you very much! You are a life savior. Just using head instead of stable for rvm worked!
